# Customizing an editable telerik mvc grids display and making it editable on click?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm trying to display a gird on a variety of screens, some very small (such as the iPhone) and some that are larger.

What I'd like to do is reduce the number of columns when it is being viewed in a small screen, so if I have columns: id, name, age, birth date, citizenship, edit/delete on a small screen it will only show name and age, if someone taps a row they get an inform editor displaying the rest of the data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to render different views based on  screen you may follow the blogpost [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx). You may use `viewport` to change the settings. In latest telerik grid release there is [columncontextmenu](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/columncontextmenu) they give the user option to select or deselect the column depending upon their need. user may user it to uncheck the column